# django grouping by a fixed list of values. Is it possible?

Tags: python, django, orm

I need to make a queryset like this:

```
c.values('month').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

which always return the twelve months including when there is no record for some of them.

Is it possible in django?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its is impossible.  Django can't read data that doesn't exist :-)

But why you don't want to build this list in python code?  Twelve dictionaries with two keys each is so small amount of data...